# JavaScript trouble subtracting variable

Tags: javascript

```
        var times_hit = $('#timeshit').val();

        if (times_hit > -1 && times_hit < 4 && times_hit != "")
        {
           if(times_hit == 0)
           {
               start_score = start_score - parseInt(times_hit.val());;
           }
```

I have tried the above. times_hit is a variable which equals 1.

If I were to do start_score = start_score - 1 it works fine.

Comment: you need to add more code to investigate. although you can try parseInt(times_hit.val());

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/seccww4r/

Comment: your if statements checks if times_hit is zero and you are expecting times_hit to be 1?????

Comment: The last `val` call should be an error, times_hit is a string

Comment: `If I were to do start_score = start_score - 1 it works fine.`. So what is not fine? What errors are you facing?

Comment: Yuo already used `.val()` when you set `times_hit`, you don't need to use it again at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You already got the input value on this line:

```
var times_hit = $('#timeshit').val();
```

You don't need to call `.val()` again when subtracting it. It should just be:

```
start_score = start_score - parseInt(times_hit, 10);
```

or just

```
start_score = start_score - times_hit;
```

since the string will be converted to a number automatically when you try to subtract it.